# string to time with python

Tags: python, time, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import bs4

root_url = 'url here'

response = requests.get(root_url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.content)
hora = soup.select('span.match-time')[0].get_text()
```

return - 20:45

I need to convert the string variable "hora" to datetime zone UTC

Update:

```
 from_zone = tz.gettz('UTC')
to_zone = tz.gettz('America/Montevideo')
utc = dt_obj.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
central = utc.astimezone(to_zone)

print(central)
```

return 1900-01-01 15:45:00-03:45

time difference is 3 hours not 3:45.
What is the matter?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

See Python's`datetime` library ([datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html))

You're going to particularly need to use `datetime.strptime` to parse 20:45. You'll also need `pytz` (`pip install pytz`) to get UTC timezone.

```
     import pytz
     import datetime

     udt = datetime.datetime.strptime(hora, '%H:%M').time().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
```

This is assuming the time you're reading is already in UTC.

Comment: in addition to resulting in 1/1/1900 as the date portion of it ... (which may be moot)

Comment: Good point haha. If you know what the date is you could start with that or also parse it if you have that info. I added .time() to the above which will give you a datetime.time object.

Comment: Also realized to make it aware you have to add the .replace() after the call to .time() -- you'd think it would inherit in when created.

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime.time(*map(int,hora_string.split(":")))
```

but you would need to know the timezone it is in in order to change it ...

you could also use the dateutil library

```
import dateutil.parser as p
print p.parse("16:45")
```

but this will attach todays date to the time , which may not be desireable

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

hora = "20:45"
the_time = dt.strptime(hora, "%H:%M").time()
```

This will return a [`datetime.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) object.

Comment: This does not return me the desired time.
However should return back 16:30 19:30

Comment: @Fabián then you need to indicate that information in your question.

Comment: hora = soup.select('span.match-time')[0].get_text().strip( ' - ' );
the_time = dt.strptime(hora, "%H:%M").time()

return 19:30 instead 16:30

Answer (score 0):

To convert UTC time to a given timezone, you need to know both date and time (utc offset may be different at a different date/time):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> input_time = datetime.strptime('20:45', '%H:%M').time()
>>> utc_dt = datetime.combine(datetime.utcnow(), input_time)
>>> tz = pytz.timezone('America/Montevideo')
>>> str(utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc).astimezone(tz))
'2015-01-24 18:45:00-02:00'
```

Note: the current offset is 2 hours, not 3. [Uruguay observes DST from October till March](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Uruguay).

Comment: Hi, problem.
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Montevideo')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'timezone'

Comment: your setup is broken. Check that it is not [the name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap). If you can't install `pytz`; ask a separate question. [ask]